# Default Webpage Not Showing Even After 72 Hours of DNS Update

Tags: domains, dns-lookup

Recently, I opened an unmanaged vps account with a2hosting.
I have installed webuzo on my account to manage it.

To proceed, I added an addon domain in my hosting account and updated the DNS entries in my namecheap account for the said domain. I updated the nameservers as what I received in the welcome mail from a2hosting.

I have also set up an A record as well as www record for my server ip address in the namecheap account for the said domain.

But it's been more than 72 hours now and I still can't see the default web page on the said domain. I could see a park page again and again.

It's been three long chat sessions with namecheap and according to them, nameservers are setup properly for the said domain as it is verified by whois lookup and related stuff.

When I opened up a ticket to webuzo support, they say that they can proceed with trouble shooting the issue only when the domain propagation is complete.

Now, first thing is that what would be the exact issue for why I can't see the default page on the said domain.

And second thing is how to proceed to resolve this issue?

Could you please guide me on this issue.

Thanking you,

Comment: You do not say... Have you created the site on your web server? Did you create the site with the site/domain name that you are expecting?

Comment: Have you checked your cache? It could be the computer you're checking from has cached the DNS entry - you'll need to flush it so it actually checks the DNS server for the new IP.

Comment: No not yet. I can upload my site on the said addon domain only when I could see the default webuzo page on that domain. The domain is not pointing to my vps yet inspite of making nameservers and A records updates accordingly.

Comment: Yes I did that. But no results so far. The issue seems to be around webuzo nameserver settings. I am gathering that information. So far finding it in discrete manner and not specific to the issue I am facing. While installing webuzo, I set my vps ip as a primary domain. I haven't setup any domain name like example.com as a primary domain in my webuzo panel and want to work on addon domains only. But only if I can resolve this very first step to proceed.

Comment: Give the names involved and people would be able to troubleshoot your problem. There is no hardcoded rule of 72 hours. It depends on various things.

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this type of issue, the first step is to bypass DNS altogether.   You can configure your own computer to use a specific IP address for any domain name.   To do so, you just need to edit your `/etc/hosts` file (or `hosts.txt` on Windows) with a line like:

```
123.123.123.123 example.com
```

Then when you visit `example.com` in your web browser it will use the IP address `123.123.123.123` for it, regardless of what the DNS servers say.   This way you can tell for sure whether it is a DNS issue, or whether it is a server configuration issue.